# Is the image closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let D(T) be the domain of T. Let D(T) $\subseteq$ X, T:D(T) -->Y closed and linear and suppose C $\subseteq$ D(T) is compact. Show that T(C) $\subseteq$ Y is closed.

I know that T is closed if and only if $x_n$ -> x $\in$ X, $Tx_n$ -> y $\in$ Y implies x $\in$ D(T), Tx=y. Now, when restricted to C, would it be as simple as $x_n$ -> x $\in$ C (due to C being compact in a normed space implying C is closed and bounded), $Tx_n$ -> y $\in$ T(C) implies Tx=y and x$\in$D(T)?

Comment: Yes, if $y$ is in the closure of $T(C)$, then there exists $\{ x_n\} \subseteq C$ such that $\{ Tx_n \}$ converges to $y$. Because $C$ is compact, there is a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to some $x \in C$, and $\{ Tx_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y$. Because $T$ is closed, $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ and $Tx=y$.

Comment: Is $C$ compact in what topology? If it is compact in the $D(T)$ topology (that is, in the graph norm) then it is immediate, as $T\colon D(T)\to Y$ is a continuous operator.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I assume that C is meant to be compact in the topology of D(T), since further information wasn't given.